# Function to check a collection is exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to create a function or something else to check if a collection is exist.

- If the collection exists - > .drop() and createCollection(nameCollection)
- If the collection does not exist - > createCollection(nameCollection)

I know how to createCollection or drop, but I dont know how to create a function that will check is exist.

#Nodejs#Mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mongodb + nodejs we can use `listCollections()` method.

```
db(<databaseName>)
  .listCollections()
  .toArray()
```

to get all the collections in an Array and then we can use bunch of Array methods (like `Array.indexOf()`) to find out whether the collection exist or not.

Link to official Docs: [listCollections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/command/listCollections/)

Comment: My collection has name 'House'. What i should do in next step to refer?